# jquery.keypad.js not working for dynamically added text box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery.keypad.js to show special characters(ÁÃÅÀ...) in the text box which user can select. It is working fine for the first field of the text box, when I add the same text field by clicking on "Add more" button it is not workin. I'm calling the function once again after clicking "Add more" even though it is not working. What could be the issue?

```
$(function () {
        $('.keypadactive').keypad({keypadClass: 'flatKeypad',keypadOnly: false, 
             layout: [<? echo  utf8_encode("'ÁÃÅÀÂÄááåàâäÆæßÇçÐÉËÈÊéëèê', 'ÌÎÍÏìîíïÑñÒÔÖØÓÕðòôöøóõÚÜÙ' ,'ÛùûúüÝýÿÿ¡,°¹²³º¼½¾±µ', '£¥\$¢þ§©®¯·¨¬«»¦ª¶'");?> ], prompt: '',showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'images/spl.jpg'});
});

$('.add_more').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().append($('#add_me_next').html());
    $(this).parent().html('<label class="w50">&nbsp;</label><input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove" class="button remove" />');

    setTimeout('keypadCall()',1000);

});

function keypadCall(){
    $('.keypadactive').keypad({keypadClass: 'flatKeypad',keypadOnly: false, 
                 layout: [<? echo  utf8_encode("'ÁÃÅÀÂÄááåàâäÆæßÇçÐÉËÈÊéëèê', 'ÌÎÍÏìîíïÑñÒÔÖØÓÕðòôöøóõÚÜÙ' ,'ÛùûúüÝýÿÿ¡,°¹²³º¼½¾±µ', '£¥\$¢þ§©®¯·¨¬«»¦ª¶'");?> ], prompt: '',showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'images/spl.jpg'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try event delegation to the closest parent which was available when dom was ready or `$(document)` itself with `.on()` handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_more', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().append($('#add_me_next').html());
    $(this).parent().html('<label class="w50">&nbsp;</label><input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove" class="button remove" />');

    setTimeout(keypadCall,1000);

});
```

and try removing the `()` from `keypadCall` function in `setTimeout()`.

Comment: It's not working, and removing () from kepadCall function in setTimeout() it is not getting into the function.

Comment: Oh my mistake you can remove the quotes `keypadCall`.